# Error enabling sshd on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, sshd, systemctl

I just installed Ubuntu Server 16.04 on a virtual machine and then installed openssh-server. When I tried to enable sshd:

```
systemctl enable sshd.service
```

I got this message:

```
Failed to execute operation: Too many levels of symbolic links
```

Does anyone know what this is? Did I forget to do something?

Comment: It is broken :) What about `systemctl status sshd.service` ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's because the service name is actually `ssh.service`, not `sshd.service`.

Do this instead:

```
systemctl enable ssh.service
```

---

#### Explanation

When you install `openssh-server`, the service is automatically enabled in systemd.  During the enabling process, a symbolic link for an enabled `sshd.service` is also created.  This symbolic link goes away if you do `systemctl disable ssh.service` or `systemctl disable sshd.service`.

You can see the symbolic link is reportedly created here:

```
root@node51 [~]# systemctl enable ssh.service
Synchronizing state of ssh.service with SysV init with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install...
Executing /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable ssh
Created symlink from /etc/systemd/system/sshd.service to /lib/systemd/system/ssh.service.
```

Because of systemd's design, systemd will not enable a service that is a symbolic link.

This is [discussed on Red Hat Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=955379).

Comment: It seems to work but I don't get the explanation, sorry. You're telling me that the service file is called "ssh.service" on ubuntu but the config file is "sshd.service"?

Comment: @SadSeven: When `ssh.service` is enabled, it creates `sshd.service` kind of as an alias.

Comment: Hmm, but how does that explain that error? "Failed to execute operation: Too many levels on symbolic links"

Comment: @SadSeven: `/etc/systemd/system/sshd.service` is a symbolic link.  SystemD won't enable a service that is a symbolic link.  [Discussion here.](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=955379)