# cannot re-enable sshd after systemd mask

Tags: ubuntu, openssh, systemd, sshd, systemctl

After disabling `sshd`, I'm having issues re-enabling/starting it via `systemctl`.

I'm sure I've hosed something, but this is what I did:

- ~fresh xubuntu 16.04.2 install
- `apt install openssh-server`

  - probably had to manually enabled it; I don't remember
  - kept default config file as-is (accessing over local LAN only)
- *(ssh'd in successfully to scp over data from a previous machine)*
- attempted to disable sshd, as I didn't intend to use it further

  - `systemctl stop sshd && systemctl disable sshd && systemctl mask sshd`
  - (did I do something wrong here?)
- now I need ssh access again, so I am trying to enable:

  - `systemctl unmask sshd` - outputs that it removed the `/dev/null` symlink
  - `systemctl enable sshd` **Failed to execute operation: No such file or directory**

Searching for solutions, I didn't find much besides what (I think) I already tried.  I have re-installed `apt remove openssh-server && apt install openssh-server`, but I am getting the same result.

An `systemctl status sshd` shows:

```
sshd.service
 Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
 Active: inactive (dead)
```

I'm not familiar with `systemctl`.  Help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: I notice that running `/usr/sbin/sshd` (no paramaters) results in the daemon running, listening on port 22, and I can now ssh in.  `systemctl status sshd` returns the same as aobve (not-found, dead)

Comment: and that `systemctl enable ssh.service` removes the `No such file` error from `systemctl status sshd` https://superuser.com/questions/1069621/error-enabling-sshd-on-ubuntu-16-04?rq=1 ... sounds between these two comments I have some bookkeeping to fix and all will be well. I'm striking out finding any concise descriptions for this, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that `sshd` is an "alias" of sorts for ssh.service; when you install openssh-server, symlink(s) are set up mapping this.

However, when you `systemctl disable sshd` those symlinks are deleted, and are NOT restored with an enable.

The solutions is to `systemctl enable ssh.service`

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled over this question with the same trace:

```
$ sudo systemctl start sshd.service
Failed to start sshd.service: Unit sshd.service is masked.
```

As suggested, `systemctl enable ssh.service` did not work.

It turned out that I had removed openssh-service.

```
dpkg -l openssh-server
```

I needed to install it again:

```
sudo apt install openssh-server
```

And the service is back:

```
$ systemctl status sshd
● ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2021-09-15 13:30:50 CEST; 1min 14s ago
       Docs: man:sshd(8)
             man:sshd_config(5)
   Main PID: 1266628 (sshd)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 18525)
     Memory: 1.5M
     CGroup: /system.slice/ssh.service
             └─1266628 sshd: /usr/sbin/sshd -D [listener] 0 of 10-100 startups
```